# Is it possible to do radix sort starting from the first digit rather than the last digit?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I know radix sort is usually done by comparing the right-most digit in a number. I am wondering if it can be done by starting from the left most digit in a number. For example, the number 2567. We would first look at the 1's place and place it into a "bucket", but can you start by looking at the 1000's place first, aka the number 2.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but there is more overhead. Assuming a read pass is done before each radix sort pass, variable size bins are created to avoid wasting space. The first most significant digit will result in 10 bins. The second most significant digit will result in 100 bins. Third digit, 1000 bins. Forth digit, 10000 bins.

For arrays of specific size, doing one or two leading "digits" could result in bins that fit within the processors cache, which helps on the radix sort passes since those are random access writes. The remainder of the radix sort on each of the bins would be least significant digit first.

---

Example code to sort 32 bit unsigned integers, where 256 bins are created and sorted by the MSB, then the 256 bins are sorted by the 3 LSB. Again, the premise here is that the array is much larger than the cache, but each of the 256 bins will fit in cache. *a* is the array to be sorted, *b* is an allocated working array the same size as *a*.

```
// split array into 256 bins according to most significant byte
void RadixSort(uint32_t * a, uint32_t*b, size_t count)
{
size_t aIndex[260] = {0};               // count / array
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)          // generate histogram
        aIndex[1+((size_t)(a[i] >> 24))]++;
    for(i = 2; i < 257; i++)            // convert to indices
        aIndex[i] += aIndex[i-1];
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)          // sort by msb
        b[aIndex[a[i]>>24]++] = a[i];
    for(i = 256; i; i--)                // restore aIndex
        aIndex[i] = aIndex[i-1];
    aIndex[0] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)            // radix sort the 256 bins
        RadixSort3(&b[aIndex[i]], &a[aIndex[i]], aIndex[i+1]-aIndex[i]);
}

// sort a bin by 3 least significant bytes
void RadixSort3(uint32_t * a, uint32_t *b, size_t count)
{
size_t mIndex[3][256] = {0};            // count / matrix
size_t i,j,m,n;
uint32_t u;
    if(count == 0)
        return;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
        u = a[i];
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u & 0xff)]++;
            u >>= 8;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){             // convert to indices
        m = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            n = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = m;
            m += n;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){             // radix sort
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
            u = a[i];
            m = (size_t)(u>>(j<<3))&0xff;
            b[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        std::swap(a, b);                //  swap ptrs
    }
}
```

Comment: That algorithm doesn't make sense. You could as well start with 10000 bins and sort values in one pass. But that wouldn't be efficient because you need to scan the 10000 bins to locate sorted values.

Comment: @chmike  - I added example code. Try it on an array around 2^24 ~= 16 million to 2^25 ~= 32 million pseudo random 32 bit unsigned integers, on a processor with 8MB cache.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but it would be less convenient and efficient than sorting from less significant to most significant.

To sort from the most significant to the less significant, you would first hash sort with the most significant digit of same weight. It would be thousands  for your example value. The result is 10 bins with values. Then for each bin, if it contains more than one value, you hash sort the values in another 10 table using the second digit. Etc.

This would require to maintain as many hash tables as there are digits while sorting. You would also need to examine more bins than with radix sort. With radix sort, we need only one hash table and visit at most n*10 bins where n is the number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is virtually no difference unless you know something about the distribution of the numbers that are to be sorted. You can also just invert the sequence of the numbers, sort by lest significant and invert the sequence of numbers again, adding a just small constant offset, the complexity stays the same.